# Removing Picklist items from multiple record types

Tags: administration, picklist, record-type

Is there a way of removing picklist items from multiple record types in one go, just as there is a way of adding picklist values to an object with multiple record types. 
For example I have `ObjectA__c` and I have a picklist called `PicklistA__c` I also have two record types for ObjectA__c called `RecordTypeA` and `RecordTypeB`. When I add an item to the picklist `PicklistA__c` for `Object__c` I get the option to select which recordtype I want to add the picklist value to. However when I want to remove the picklist value from certain record types I can only do this by going to the picklist field `PickListA__c` on the individual record type and removing it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the faster way is to **edit** the `Object__c.object`.

There you'll find the `RecordTypeB` definition where all the `PicklistA__c` related values are.

By removing the values you don't want within the RecordType definition and save the file your task will be done.